# Aligning text to coordinates (not moving in y-axis)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to align an image but for some reason it is not aligning in the Y-axis (i.e. i can't move the image up or down). It does move in the X-axis however.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

I am using the alignment(X,Y) function as below:

```
      Container(
        height: 350,
        width: 200,
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.5),
            child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/student-teacher.svg'),),

      ),
```

Comment: Are you sure that you pasted correct code, because it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a width to your Container.